# Spring security : Http security method in jwt

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, jjwt

I am trying to implement the jwt login example

while configuring configure method for security class I am facing some issue

here is the method for the controller

```
@PostMapping("api/user/login")
public ResponseEntity<?> login(Principal principal)
{
    if (principal == null)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(principal);
    }
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal;
    User user = userService.findByUsername(token.getName());
    user.setToken(jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(token));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here I have the http configure version

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
    throws Exception
{
    http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/error", "/api/user/**")
        .permitAll().antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest()
        .fullyAuthenticated().and().logout().permitAll()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/user/logout", "POST")).and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/api/user/login/").permitAll().and().httpBasic().and().csrf()
        .disable();
    http.addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtTokenProvider));
}
```

Clearly I have allowed the login api as permitall, but still it going for the filter, could anyone explain what exactly going on

filter code

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException,
    ServletException
{
    Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(request);
    if (authentication != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(request))
    {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

as per my learning it should not go in filter code, if I have allowed as permitall in http configure.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you making this request from the browser or through Postman client? If you are making from your frontend client, make sure that you don't add the Authorization header to the request.

Comment: I am making this request from browser

Comment: Can you try adding, 

`@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)  {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/user/login/");
}`

Comment: I already have "/api/user/**". Do you still think, i need the above line of code